# How to print reports with non-English characters like accents?

Tags: civireport, localisation, reports

We have instances of CiviCRM in Spanish and Catalan. When we try to print some reports the Spanish and Catalan specific characters (accents, 
umlauts, etc.) are printed with a wrong charset. E.g. It prints **RelaciÃ³** instead of **Relació**

It is a bug or we're missing something?

Comment: It seems from your response that you are using Apache, but could you provide more information about the type of web server you are using? (version, operating system, etc). This should normally work by default. It could also be related to the theme of your CMS (drupal/wp/joomla?), that might be missing the "meta encoding" tag.

Comment: We use:
    apache 2.2.22-13+deb7u6
    php 5.4.45-0+deb7u2
    mysql 5.5.46-0+deb7u1
We run also
    drupal 7 over garland theme
    civicrm 4.6.8 over garland theme

Answer (score 3):

Although not an ideal solution, if we add the following line in the .htaccess the reports are printed well.

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably caused by the settings for your database? We had the same problem with Norwegian special characters because their CiviCRM database was set to Latin-1. It has to be UTF-8 general-ci for CiviCRM.

Comment: Not in our case. All database tables are set to UTF-8.

Comment: I know the special chars problem in 2 scenario's: the database one I mentioned and when importing or exporting with csv with the wrong encoding. You solution also suggests something somewhere with encoding:-)

Comment: it might well be you default charset is not utf-8 as you have to change it?